# how to determine if video file is 'high quality' using bitrate and dimensions?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Assuming a directory full of videos, if you extracted the video metadata to get video bitrate and dimensions. Is there a recommend way to plug in these values and get a LOW/HI quality answer.

I would like to sort videos into a LOW/HI quality directory layout but after using ffmpeg to get the meta data, it isn't obvious how to programmatically ascertain the videos quality.

Is this possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: A crude method is the bits per pixel metric i.e. `Bitrate/(W x H x FPS)`, but this will fail if your content is of different types i.e. live-action vs. 2D anim vs. screen-recordings..etc, since the bitrate required for adequate fidelity is different. There are no-reference visual quality metrics which measure edge sharpness, blocking, ringing..etc to judge quality but I don't see any filters in the main ffmpeg builds that do this. Also, see [this](http://superuser.com/q/338725/114058).

Comment: ok thank you. I will try your method or fallback to parsing the information and apply some weight based on meta. Shorter duration + larger filesize/high bitrate i suppose will be of higher quality than a video with longer duration and smaller size/low bitrate.